# what should you do when you realize you stupidly asked a question on the wrong site AND had a bounty?

Tags: discussion, moving-questions

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/209717/cannot-access-client-pc-remotely-due-to-time-date-issue-xp-win2k3-environment) should've gone to ServerFault, I'm thinkin'. Maybe I could just delete it and re-ask over there. Will I lose the bounty? It is sort of a SuperUser question, but it dawned on me that it would have had a better response over there after I had already bountied it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators can undo the bounty if you like. Flag it for moderator attention and indicate you want the bounty removed if you feel strongly about it.

Comment: I imagine people might get angry if I tried waiting until the last minute before getting it removed. Is there a reasonable window for seeing if I can get quality responses here first?

Comment: Well there's always a good excuse and as long as you don't abuse it, nobody will complain and probably even notice it!

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is better suited and may even receive a higher quality answer, it is still within the bounds of the Super User asking.  I would wait and see if there are any good quality answers that come in.  I'm pretty sure that the bounty is set in stone and that your rep is now gone and is definately not transferable to other sites.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a wait and see then.